# How do I create a new classic asp project in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, asp-classic

I'm trying to create a new classic asp project in Azure, to run my company's web site. We will be upgrading it later to .NET but I'm only just starting with that so I am not sure how this goes.

I have an Azure account and can create web apps till the cows come home but I can't get them to run under classic asp. I've tried all the Google tips to no avail. Is there anyone out there who can help!

Comment: You can use WebMatrix (http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) to create web sites that can be hosted on Azure (I've got a few). Or you can use Meteor for freely hosted sites, too. I would recommend that you just jump in and go with ASP.NET, though (which you can also do via WebMatrix).

Comment: Azure allows up to 10 websites hosted for free. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/net/aspnet/ ASP will work.

Comment: Note that asp.net and classic asp are about as similar as Java and JavaScript: their names are similar and they serve a similar purpose, and that's about it. In other words, if what you want to use is asp.net, just use asp.net right off, because anything you write in asp-classic will need to be thrown out once you convert. (I don't know if "upgrade" is the right word.)

Comment: I was able to run a sample Classic ASP page (with a line of VBScript code - http://www.w3schools.com/asp/) hosted as Azure Web App with absolutely no steps other than creating a file under wwwroot. If you're trying out simple experimental stuff, you can build a sample page with just your browser  - http://mvark.blogspot.in/2016/02/publish-website-in-minutes-with-kudu.html . I haven't gone thru the video @shahed-c-msft has shared in his answer but no "elevated startup task" is required. It runs directly without any configuration required.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to run Classic ASP on Azure by running an elevated startup task.

More info is available in the following video on MSDN Channel 9:

https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Cloud-Cover-Episode-31-Startup-Tasks-Elevated-Privileges-and-Classic-ASP

Hope that helps!